# Is there a way to validate that a lambda function passed as an argument only assigns True or False?

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I'm currently working on an in-house framework that we use for ETL operations and one component of that is writing functions that perform commonly used operations for DataFrames. The current function I'm working on will take in a function that will assign True or False to a record in a DataFrame. Then it will drop records where the function evaluated to true for a record (for the default behaviour).

The function is currently working as it should, but you would get unexpected behaviour if you passed in a function that assigned values other than True or False to a record. My problem is that I don't know how to do that or if it's even possible. I'm familiar with the basics of validating arguments, but I'm at a loss for how I might check that a function passed as an argument meets certain standards.

The function and its arguments are called like this within the workflow:

```
udo.call(
        "drop_records", #function name
        drop_func= lambda x: True if (x["Discussion"] == True)|(x["Internal"] == False) else False,
        drop_true= False
    )
```

And the function is defined below:

```
def drop_records(self,input_data,params):
        drop_func = params["drop_func"]
        try:
            drop_true = params["drop_true"]
        except:
            drop_true = True
        try:
            drop_col = params["drop_col"]
        except:
            drop_col = "drop_col"

        df = input_data.copy(deep=True)

        df[drop_col] = df.apply(drop_func, axis=1)
        df.drop(df.loc[df[drop_col]==drop_true].index,inplace=True)
        df.drop(columns=[drop_col],inplace=True)
        df.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)

        return df
```

I thought about making some kind of list to run the function on and check it, but that doesn't look like it will work because (a) the function is applied to the DataFrame using apply(), so the user will be specifying columns unique to their data and (b) I can't know what kind of data they will be using in the function ahead of time. Am I thinking through that incorrectly and missing something simple?

Comment: Are you referring to type checks(in your case BOOLean) as preconditions?

Comment: Similar to a type check, but same principle. Rather than checking the type of argument drop_func, I'm trying to check the types of any outputs of drop_func after it is applied to a dataset to ensure that the function cannot assign a value that isn't True or False.

Comment: Terrible way to do it, but you could use eval

Comment: How would I be able to use that in this context?